# Why isn't background-position working?

Tags: html, css, background-position

I don't often use background-position, so maybe I'm not doing this correctly, but my css rule is not taking effect.

`background-position:right 353px bottom 20px;`

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<h1> 
    <a href="#">
        <img src="/images/silver-corner-logo.jpg" id="site-title" />
    </a>
</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    width:80%;height:154px;
    min-width:353px;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    text-align:right;
    background-color:#A8A9AD;
    background-image:url("/images/top-left.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right 353px bottom 20px;
}
#site-title {
    margin:0;padding:0;
    display:block;
    width:353px;
    float:right;
}
```

**EDIT**

It Occurs to me that maybe I should describe what it is I am trying to accomplish.

Within my h1, I have a logo (width 353).
The h1 may become larger than 353 depending on the screen size.

In this case I want a background image to display to adjacent (left) to the img so that it will nicely fade into the solid background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What browser are you using? Four values for `background-position` is only supported in a couple of them (Firefox, Chrome and Safari do NOT support it). [Documented here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position)

Comment: Hahah, I've been at that page the whole time, and didnt see that.  Silly me.  Guesse it would work with IE9 or Opera...

Answer (score 2):

That's not the proper syntax for `background-position`, as indicated by [this documentation](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position).

`right` and `bottom` do not have numeric arguments, but stand alone.

Comment: hmm, I have been using MDN [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position] as a reference.  They give the example: background-position: right 20px bottom 20px;

Comment: @Zach: Read the section on that page entitled "browser compatibility".

Answer (score 0):

background-position:**right 353px bottom 20px;**

It is confusing, following shows how to use background:position.

Optionsof position

```
left top
left center
left bottom
right top
right center
right bottom
center top
center center
center bottom
```

If you only specify one keyword, the other value will be "center"

```
x% y%
```

The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0% 0%. The right bottom corner is 100% 100%. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. . Default value is: 0% 0%